# New-minimal vs old-minimal supergravity

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, supersymmetry, action, supergravity, duality

New-minimal set of supergravity auxiliary fields includes a two-form field, whereas the old-minimal auxiliary set includes a vector and a complex scalar. Is anyone aware of how to transform between the two resulting actions in the situations where the auxiliary fields actually play a role, like matter coupled SUGRA, or $R+R^2$ model?